# Test significance of added factor with date based data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, statistical-significance

I have the value of a dependent variable, Y, for every day from 1/1/2000 to 12/31/2016.  The value is partially dependent on the day of the year/week/month, the month, and the year; as well as on other variables.  I'm training my model using 2000-2015 and testing using 2016.  If I have a model that predicts Y based on the day and factors X[1]...X[N], how do I determine whether any added accuracy from new factor X[N+1] is statistically significant.  If it weren't for the date dependency, I would use bootstrap or other random sampling techniques across multiple runs.  It doesn't seem like removing random dates or days of the year is a good approach.

Comment: If you're using regression of some kind, look into what's variously called a sequential or multi-stage or hierarchical use of regression.  That will show, beyond what the other factors can do, how much the new factor can do to predict Y.

Comment: Thanks, Rolando2.  I will look into that, but I'm using neural networks and XGBoost, so I really need something that just looks at the result of the loss function for each run.